# R convert data into a vector

Tags: r, bioinformatics, seurat

I have an object (Seurat object) an I need to get certain data out of it

```
> sc@misc[["colors"]][["seurat_clusters"]]
          0           1           2           3           4           5           6           7 
"#CC0C00FF" "#5C88DAFF" "#84BD00FF" "#FFCD00FF" "#7C878EFF" "#00B5E2FF" "#00AF66FF" "#CC0C00B2"
```

This data is needed as an vector but I don't know how to pull "#CC0C00FF" "#5C88DAFF" etc. out of it.

In order to hand this data to the next function, the result should look like this:

```
> vec
[1] "#CC0C00FF" "#5C88DAFF" "#84BD00FF"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `sc@misc[["colors"]][["seurat_clusters"]][1]`  ?

Comment: Then I get the first entry 
`> sc@misc[["colors"]][["seurat_clusters"]][1]`
          `0` 
`"#CC0C00FF" `

Comment: Then play with the number at the end like:  `sc@misc[["colors"]][["seurat_clusters"]][2]` or `sc@misc[["colors"]][["seurat_clusters"]][1:3] `

Comment: @maydin Then I always have this weird format `0` `"#CC0C00FF"` and therefore the next function can't handle the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it! I'm pretty disappointed by myself, because I didn't know this function existed:

```
> as.vector(sc@misc[["colors"]][["seurat_clusters"]])
[1] "#CC0C00FF" "#5C88DAFF" "#84BD00FF" "#FFCD00FF" "#7C878EFF" "#00B5E2FF" "#00AF66FF" "#CC0C00B2"
```

Comment: Just for your understanding, `as.vector` is almost certainly not needed: the result *already  is* a vector. That vector has names (which are stripped by `as.vector`) so it is displayed differently. But these names shouldn’t be a problem, so you don’t *need* to strip them. (I’m basing this on the output of your code … it’s possible that what’s returned is actually something different, but that’s unlikely).

Comment: Something else, you can probably simplify the code by using name access instead of subsetting based on a value. That is, you can write `sc@misc$colors$seurat_clusters` instead of what you’ve written.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I also thought these names shouln't be a problem. The doc says "Also accepts a Brewer color scale or vector of colors" and your example `is.vector(sc@misc$colors$seurat_clusters)
[1] TRUE`. Nontheless the function only runs if I remove the names.